# Javascript keys error. How to correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

I just downloaded the spritely jQuery plugin: http://spritely.net/
I would like to tell the plugin that at frame 11 (last frame of the animation) I would like to reverse the animation. Here's my code:

```
$('#logo').sprite({
    fps: 17,
    no_of_frames: 12,
    on_frame: {
    11: function(obj) {
        rewind: true
        }
    }
});
```

the **rewind: true** functions works if placed as an option next to fps, no_of_frames etc. But I need it only initialized when at frame 11.

How can this be achieved?

Many thanks!

Comment: `rewind: true` is not a valid line of Javascript.

Comment: yeah i got that... It should give you an idea of what I am trying to do. How do I do it right?

Comment: I'll get it for you; hold on.  Give me some HTML.  I don't want to invent markup myself.

Comment: Uhmm.. Here you go? 
<body>
<div id="logo"></div>
</body>

Comment: Ha, I'm sorry.  I looked past your code only noting it was JavaScript, so forgive me.  Any CSS or image-related data I need?  Oh, man, I got this.

Comment: Sure. Ok so i gave u the html. Here's the CSS:

#body {
    background:#000;
}
#logo {
 width:160px;
 height:108px;
 background:url(http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/5382/logoanimated.png); 
}

Comment: Great. Gimme a minute. Hos before code, bro.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13705/discussion-between-gabriel-ryan-nahmias-and-ilya-karnaukhov)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the documentation for that plugin and instead of using JavaScript for this, I would consider making a GIF, which I bothered to do for you.  You will end up having more control over the appearance probably, too.  If you'd still like me to look into the programmatic solution for you, please let me know.  Also, could you tell me the name of the font you used?  The reason I ask is some of the frames you sent me ended up not being exactly aligned; I can redo it.  Here you go: http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/7084/bigom.gif

Comment: Thanks mate. You really didn't have to go through all that trouble ^^ Since I couldn't figure out how to do that, I did something different. When the logo is hovered it swings the g back and forth once then stop. Instead of using the rewind method I just added more frames to make the g swing back animation. :)